# Getting an Error while launching jmeter 3.2

Tags: jmeter, slf4j, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to execute jmeter 3.2 batch file but application is not working

My log with error:

```
C:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin>jmeter.bat
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.2/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.2/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

> Don't use GUI mode for load testing, only for Test creation and Test debugging !
For load testing, use NON GUI Mode:
   jmeter -n -t [jmx file] -l [results file] -e -o [Path to output folder]
& adapt Java Heap to your test requirements:
   Modify HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" in the JMeter batch file

> An error occurred: org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextScrollPane.<init>(Lorg/fife/ui/rtextarea/RTextArea;)V
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

As message tell you, yoy have 2 bindings for slf4j, so remove one, for example:

- C:/apache-jmeter-3.2/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.10.jar